# Query for count the total number of orders and sent orders per customer (return 0 if none)

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables `Order` with columns:

```
orderId(int), name(varchar), customerId(int), sent(bool), deleted(bool)
```

And `Customer` with columns:

```
customerId(int), name(varchar), address(varchar), deleted(bool)
```

I need to return all `Customer` columns, with additional `TotalOrders` count and `TotalSentOrders` count columns (for each customer) for the Customers and Orders that `deleted = false` and count 0 if there are no orders or sent orders.

Expected Outcome:

```
|customerId|name|address|deleted|TotalOrders|TotalSentOrders|
|     1    |John| A St. | false |     0     |       0       |
|     2    |Jack| B St. | false |     5     |       1       |
|     3    |Luke| C St. | false |     4     |       0       |
```

I'm doing this in PostgreSQL 9.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=dd7939fe543ef1b8459788e6ca02631c)

```
SELECT
    c.*,
    COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE o.orderId IS NOT NULL),    -- 3
    COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE o.sent = true)             -- 4
FROM customer c
LEFT JOIN orders o ON c.customerId = o.customerId     -- 1
WHERE c.deleted = false AND o.deleted = false         -- 2
GROUP BY c.customerId, c.name, c.address, c.deleted
```

1. `LEFT JOIN` both tables, to keep `John`s data
2. Remove all `deleted`
3. `GROUP BY` customer and `COUNT` the remaining records. Because `John` is still in the result set, he would be counted as well. To ensure you only count the orders you could use the `FILTER` clause to adjust the aggregate function.
4. Use the `FILTER` clause once more to `COUNT` only the `sent` orders.

Comment: Thank you so much! I just add to the Where Clause (besides c.deleted = false) o.deleted = false in order to get orders that are not deleted as well

Comment: Sorry I forgot to test the scenario where There are no orders for that Customer. In that scenario your query does not return Count 0 it just don't return (display) that customer at all.

Comment: What do you mean? See the fiddle. There's no order for John, and so it results in 0. That's why you need the first FILTER

Comment: I've found out what happened. After I added o.deleted = false to your where clause John is not displayed anymore, in fiddle works because that's not added :/ Is there a way to just count orders that had been marked as deleted = false?

Comment: I add o.deleted = false inside Filter Where clause and it works. Thanks man!!

Comment: Otherwise you could filter these items before joining, which would be more performant, I guess: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=e7fca808f32a1773d8fe233c356d2d73

Comment: Thanks for accepting! I'd appreciate if you could upvote as well :) (Now that you gained the vote priviledge ;) )

Comment: @HectorLeon . . . This would filter out customers with no orders.  But your question suggests that you want those.

Comment: Well, adding an `ORDER BY c.customerId` should do the magic ;) https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=fc26c5914a3d95b349d03c858d83b8fc